# Do individual persons have corresponding mudras according to body Constitution?

Tags: body, mudra

Kapha body means earth + water.. So is there corresponding mudra for that person ie thumb joined with ring and little finger? 
And what will be the effect.. Will dosha get balanced?

Comment: Yes they have. For example if a person whose dominant Tattva is Agni does Prithvi Mudra then he/she will feel uneasy.. (bcoz Agni and Prithvi are opposite of one another)... And to know one's Tattva astrology comes handy... Hint is that the 27 Naksatras are divided into Agni, Jala, Prithvi etc groups...

Comment: How the pancha bootha is working in one's body matters....Each one is dominated in life by 1 bootha and that 1 is different for each one.

Comment: Is that tattva same as our dosha we find in ayurveda. And can it be reliably found from questionnaire available online?